Is there a way to add Local Symbol names in the ELF file by adding debug flags to the arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler?
I am able to view the global symbols such as functions, global/static variables in the final built executable in elf file. I am looking for compilation flags that can add the local variable names into the symbol table.
I tried multiple debug flags to the compiler such -g3, -ggdb, -gdwarf-3 but I was not successful. First of all, is it possible to add local symbol information by any chance? If so, How to do it?

As Andrew says, it's not possible to represent stack variables in symbol tables, but they'll be described in DWARF debug info. After compiling with
your choice of -g??? option run readelf --debug-dump=info <your_binary> to see it. This expresses the data gdb uses to display execution of the code.

Assuming that local variable names means names of variables within functions, then no, this is not possible.
The symbol table maps a name to a single address.  A local variable, within a function can have different addresses through the life time of your program.  A local variable might not even be placed in memory, but instead held in a register.  The symbol table can't model this.
When you add the -g flag, the compiler adds debug information, most likely in DWARF format, to your program.  The DWARF information can represent all the details of your local variables.

I see. Thanks. Will look into DWARF Format.
